# How to show a control over and embedded executable?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, z-index, user32

I am using WPF for my application (for Windows 7/8.1/10).

I am embedding inside an external executable thanks to **User32** functions :

```
SetParent(...); // Setting Hwnd parent
SetStyle(...); // Removing border
SetWindowPos(...); // Setting size and position
```

However, this element stays on top of everything. I would like to be able to have a control of my main application on top of the embedded one.

I don't know if this is possible. I tried passing `HWND_BOTTOM` in `SetWindowPos(...)` and adding `Panel.ZIndex="1000"` to the XAML of the object that should be topmost but it doesn't work for me.

Any solution / tricks for this ? Thanks !

Comment: Please explain more of the details. What are you embedding where? Why do you have to use Win32? Do you want to embed a WPF control in some other window like stated in the title? Or do you want to just show a WPF window like indicated in the text? And if the latter is the case, why do you even "embed" a window using Win32 as a child window of an external executable and not just simply show your WPF window? What do you want to accomplish? Do you want to kind of hijack the external application?

Comment: I want to embed a standalone executable inside my WPF application. It behaves exactly like notepad.exe for instance.
Let's imagine I have a WPF window with a 2x1 grid. I want to place a notepad.exe window in the first half of the grid and then have a button on top of notepad.exe

Comment: You can only have windows above other windows - never only a single control above some window. So if you have a WPF window with an external window above it and you want to add something above that external window you absolutely have to show another WPF window containing your button and place it on top of the external window using Win32.

Comment: I totally agree with @IInspectable that you should stop what you're trying to accomplish here because it's just an overall bad concept.

Comment: Thanks for your concern but there are some constrains which are inputs to my problem. I do not have any control over the fact that I have to embed an executable application for which I don't have any source code. And the article you linked actually says that it is legal.

Comment: If I were doing things the right way I wouldn't need to post to SO because of how easy it would for me to find the information I need. The issue is that here I have to deal with a non standard case. Please understand that.

Comment: @OdgyGsf Then you definitely have to show a second WPF window containing your button that you want to display on top of the external window. I don't see any other way to accomplish that exotic wish. (Of course except from really hijacking the external window and injecting your code directly in there using some seriously bad Win32 calls.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Even if I am a bit stuck, you are helping me. IInspectable I'd recommend to get Leil Lowndes's [How to Talk to Anyone](https://www.amazon.com/How-Talk-Anyone-Success-Relationships/dp/007141858X/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&qid=1436767403&sr=8-2&keywords=how+to+talk+to+anybody&linkCode=sl1&tag=impyousocski-20&linkId=9a816b1102fe0a16c126e7c96454cac8) and work it from there.

Comment: @OdgyGsf: Yes, it's legal, in the same way it's legal to juggle chain saws. How long have you been practicing? Plan to invest about a decade until you have a firm grip on the intricate details you need to know, before you can plan to break the rules. And in case of a 3rd party application that you do not control, there is absolutely, positively no way to implement this in a safe fashion. If you read that blog entry and still believe that you are on the right track, I cannot help you. It **clearly** explains, why your proposed solution to the problem is impossible.

Comment: I never said I was looking for a "safe fashion". Actually I even **clearly** said that I was looking for a trick. StackOverflow is primarly about helping others. If you want to help, i think you should first have to inform yourself about the actual context. More over, it is possible, as pointed out haindl, although being and extreme hack. And please stop making judgements about people you don't know.

Comment: “If you can't solve a problem, it's because you're playing by the rules” - Paul Arden

Comment: *"And if you're breaking the rules, you no longer have a solution."* - IInspectable